# Create dynamically componnent with directive angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-directive, dynamically-generated, angular-components

I would like to create component dynamically (by selector) with directive like it written in template component. (See exemple bellow)

```
<text-gui dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i"
      dnd-draggable [dragEnabled]="true" [dragData]="feat"></text-gui>
```

I've success to create component, but i don't find how to apply directives.

Bellow, the creator of component

```js
  public generateGUIElement( vcRef: ViewContainerRef, feat: ElementCreator ) {
    const factories    = Array.from( this.resolver[ '_factories' ].values() );
    const factory: any = factories.find( ( x: any ) => x.selector === feat.gui );

    vcRef.createComponent( factory );
  }
```

Bellow the result

```
<text-gui class="d-block" ng-version="4.0.3">...</text-gui>
```

It's possible to do what i would ? Thx for your answer.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?